# Installation of Visual Studio On Linux Machine

Tags: asp.net, linux, ubuntu

Please tell me how can i install `Visual Studio` any version on `linux`
Like `UBUNTU 11.0`

Comment: have you try to use [wine](http://www.winehq.org/)?

Comment: no i'm searching something like linux version

Comment: you need a IDE or need use c#?

Comment: i just want to install visual studio on linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). It allows for .NET support and the ability to run ASP.NET. You also might want to check out [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) which is an IDE like Visual Studio expect it is cross platform.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Though I can definitely see no point in trying to run something like ASP.NET with a non-native workaround under Linux. I would stick to Windows for my ASP.NET-specific development, and keep Linux for other stuff.