# ASP.NET environment on Linux

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installation of Visual Studio On Linux Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732158/installation-of-visual-studio-on-linux-machine)

I'm usually working with python/php and such, but now my professor demand me to work with Visual Studio 2010. Bad news is, I don't have a Windows OS, so - 
Are there any options to get **Visual Studio 2010 up and running on Debian/Ubuntu**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run Visual Studio on Linux. You can run [Mono Develop](http://monodevelop.com/) and create ASP.NET projects in it. It works pretty good.

Other alternative. Install [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), install Windows and then VS.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use a virtual machine - the guest would be running Windows. Check [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/) - you may be able to get Windows Server 2008 R2 (and other software) for free if your school participates.

If you look at Wine, [Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 are not doing very well](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892), so that's not a real option at this time.

The [mono project](http://go-mono.org) has a free C# IDE - [Mono Develop](http://monodevelop.com/), though it is not Visual Studio it is quite fully featured and supports ASP.NET development.

Comment: Frankly, WINE is soooo behind that is almost only useful if you plan to run some kind of game. :/

Comment: @Icarus - true, but for VS 2008 and before, still a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Visual Studio you will have to install WINE (but do not think it's a good solution)

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892

But you can also use the Mono Project

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Or just install a Virtual Machine with a windows OS

You are free to choose what best suits your needs

Comment: If you look at that WINE page, you will see that the support for the newer Visual Studio versions is poor.